# How can I fix this line

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy import stats

 

mu, sigma = 0,2

x= mu + sigma*np.random.randn(25000)

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 25, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.75)

 

import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

y = mlab.normpdf( bins, mu, sigma)

l = plt.plot(bins, y, 'r--', linewidth=5)

plt.xticks(fontsize=12, rotation=0)

plt.yticks(fontsize=12, rotation=90)

plt.xlabel('x', fontsize=16, color='blue')

plt.ylabel('normal', fontsize=16, color='blue')

plt.title(r'$\mathrm{Histogram\ of\ IQ:}\ \mu=0.0, \ \sigma=2.0$')
```

```
NameError
Traceback (most recent call last)
  <command-1361783690544063> in <cell line: 1>()
    ----> 1 plt.title(r'$\mathrm{Histogram\ of\ IQ:}\ \mu=0.0, \ \sigma=2.0$')
NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
```

I tried removing line 16, I tried removing section of the code.

Comment: You are somehow trying to run that single line of code by itself, rather than the entire script (which contains the definition of `plt`).  "Don't do that" is really all I can say.

Comment: Define `plt` before executing this line.

Comment: It says "cell", so maybe you're using something like Jupyter Notebook and accidentally running the cells out of order?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips like how to write a good title and making a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

First, `matplotlib.mlab.normpdf` has been [deprecated](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.0/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.normpdf) for years now (more than a decade actually), you should use `scipy.stats.norm.pdf` instead

The fact that a single line executes and that you're [not calling plt.show()](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9486) indicates that you may be using a notebook, in which case you should make sure that you call the imports before the remaining of the code

After correcting the normpdf thing the code works for me:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.stats import norm

mu, sigma = 0, 2

x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(25000)

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 25, facecolor="blue", alpha=0.75)

y = norm.pdf(bins, mu, sigma)

plt.plot(bins, y, "r--", linewidth=5)

plt.xticks(fontsize=12, rotation=0)
plt.yticks(fontsize=12, rotation=90)

plt.xlabel("x", fontsize=16, color="blue")
plt.ylabel("normal", fontsize=16, color="blue")

plt.title(r"$\mathrm{Histogram\ of\ IQ:}\ \mu=0.0, \ \sigma=2.0$")

plt.show()
```

Which yields this
[image: The output I get]

Lastly, I hope this is not the real IQ distribution :')

Comment: A helpful student, hehe. :^) First half is acceptable as an answer however the last half should be a comment.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to comment sadly :'), will edit to ramble a little less

Comment: Looks great! Will upvote as soon as my daily vote quota resets. :^)

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I am using notebook. I am not sure about the editor.

Comment: Is everything in the same cell? If not, make sure to run them in the right order or to put all the code in the same cell

Comment: @user22366511 could you provide more information about the problem you still have or accept this answer?